Capture text block(s) starting with specific header and containing keyword(s)
I am trying to capture text blocks which start with the header Sender: or From: and contain the keyword SOA.
Original text
Sender: 
John Doe 
This is an email about Service-Oriented Architecture (SOaaA). 
From:Jane Smith 
body: This email is unrelated to SOA. 
Sender:John Doe 
body:none 
Sender:Jenny 
Let's learn SOA! 

My trial
(^(From:|Sender:)(([\s\S]*)SOA)*?)(?!(From:|Sender:))

I expect to capture 2 groups as,
Group-1
From:Jane Smith 
body: This email is unrelated to SOA.

Group-2
Sender:Jenny 
Let's learn SOA! 

but I don't get good result. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! Samuel

Please mention the environment. It sounds like with capture two groups you rather mean get two matches? However, you can temper the [\s\S] with the lookahead, something like: ^(?:From|Sender):(?:(?!From|Sender)[\s\S])*\bSOA\b.* or in PCRE a bit shorter with reference.

If you know, next line contains body e.g. ^(?:From|Sender):.*\r?\n.*\bSOA\b.* is much cheaper.

((?:From:|Sender:).*\n.*SOA.*)

The above works for me, using multiline flag, using the Javascript engine, tested on https://www.regextester.com/
